# How do i create this rough black effect in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, photo-editing

[image]

I want to create this blackish rough effect on fighters and i have tried different things but I'm unable to achieve this precise effect. Need help here!!

How this effect could be achieved? thanks

Comment: What rough effect? Looks pretty smooth to me so really not sure which part of the image you're referring to.

Answer (score 2):

Original image from [unsplash.com](https://unsplash.com/photos/ThqaTYD_l0o)

[image]

- Duplicate the layer masking what's outside the main figure
- Menu **Image** > **Adjustments** > **Desaturate**
- Change the blend mode to **Multiply**
- Adjust the opacity percentage if necessary

[image]

- Create a 100% black **Fill Layer** using the same mask
- Change the blend mode to **Color**
- Adjust the opacity percentage if necessary

[image: Color]

- Make the last retouches adjusting the shadows, midtones and highlight levels of the second layer

[image: levels]

**Result**

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

I intentionally took the *opposite* workflow approach to contrast with and show an alternative workflow to Danielillo's excellent answer.

This is why I choose to use *positive* selection of the fighter, masked adjustment layers for him, and then for a bit more pop, I did the same thing with the wristband.

My goal was to get a slightly more "statuesque" feel from this base image, crushing the mid tones a bit more into the darker, implying hopefully an almost metallic or polished marble type of highlight, and therefore implying more "hardness" to our fighter, ***but*** hopefully with*out* losing too much in-shadow detail.

In my case I used Affinity Photo, but the same basic approach would work just as well with Photoshop.

I used the selection brush and refined edges to get a good selection set for just the fighter himself, isolating him from all other elements, including his wristband.

[image]

I applied a simple Black and white adjustment layer, setting yellow as my strongest white, setting red as mid-dark, and got to a pretty good base tonality right off the bat.

[image]

Then I added a brightness-contrast adjustment Layer to give more pop and control the contrast interactively.

[image]

Then I added a shadows-highlights adjustment Layer to tweaks shadow depth and highlight pop and give those shadows a bit more high-def feel, but with better control and subtlety than the straight contrast adjustment.

[image]

Then I added a lens adjustment Layer - this one's a bit subtle but it allows a slight shift of underlying tonality.

[image]

At this point I was quite happy with how the fighter himself has turned out, relative to our OP's example poster, but I wasn't happy with how his wristband was looking in comparison and how it seemed a bit washed out compared to the rope pads.

Knowing I was thinking of having a series of differing adjustment areas, one for the fighter and most likely one for the wristband and maaaybe one for the rope pad, I nested the fighter's adjustment layers into a named group (with opacity at Passthrough) to make managing these simpler and clearer.

So then I used the selection brush to create a selection of just the wristband, isolating it from every other element in the image, and started another adjustment group targeting the wristband - I added a vibrance adjustment Layer bringing the wristband's chroma up just a tad.

[image]

So then I decided I wanted to swing the specific hue of the wristband a bit closer to the hue of the rope pad beneath - to limit the overall colour palette and give that accent colour a bit more weight in the composition - so I added a recolour adjustment layer.

[image]

I then completed my desired hue transition with a colour balance adjustment layer (note that all of these remain live non-destructive and re-editable) and felt like this was about where I wanted it for this context.

[image]

And here we are with the final image:

[image]